# How do I set margins for buttons on the same row in a responsive way?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I currently have a few buttons on a line that I have horizontally but would like to add margins to push the buttons away from each other.

I was editing my code in a smaller window and the buttons were spaced fine using CSS margins, but when I maximized the window I noticed that the margins between the buttons either pushed some buttons to a new line or pulled them back.

I haven't been able to find a way to set margins for these buttons on the same row in a responsive way so they don't push to a new line or pull back.

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-submitpadding">Submit</button>
        <a href="/select-all" class="btn btn-default btn-selectspacer">Select All</a>
        <a href="/deselect-all" class="btn btn-default">Deselect All</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-infospacer" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#helpInfo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="helpInfo">More Info</a></button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-selectspacer {
    margin-left: 40em;
}

.btn-infospacer {
    margin-left: 2.25em;
}

.btn-submitpadding {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}
```

**Image**
[Button Spaced with margins horizontally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcQae.png)

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Please include your css for the wrapper around your buttons. It can be due to having a fixed width in your div or wrapper in certain screen sizes.

Comment: @ShahGhafoori Shah, I don't have any CSS for a wrapper around the buttons, they are only implemented in the HTML and CSS pasted above.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the grid system that comes with Bootstrap. For example the Submit taking up 9 col's, the select/all taking up 2 and then more info taking up 1. And then just align the submit button to be on the left of the column.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, so if I did say col-md-9 for Submit, select/all col-md-2, and col-md-1 for the info button that would work in theory.

I would also have to specify sizes for small and extra small so they would stack correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple solution for what you need. I tried out my self, results are just like you want in attached image.
As if you are testing it in very large devices, I would recommend you to download the following bootstrap css for extra large devices.
[BOOTSTRAP CSS FOR EXTRA LARGE DEVICES](https://github.com/marcvannieuwenhuijzen/BootstrapXL)
Put this css below your bootstrap css file and you can then use another column class like "col-xl-numbers of columns". For your specific case i am adding "col-xs-12" to the button div.
Note: Upcomming Bootstrap 4 has built in class for extra large devices.
You css should only be

```
   .btns-right {
     float:right; 
     margin-right:5%; 
   }

  .btn-submitpadding {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
   }
```

and your html should be

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-submitpadding">Submit</button>

    <div class="btns-right">
        <a href="/select-all" class="btn btn-default btn-selectspacer">Select All</a>
        <a href="/deselect-all" class="btn btn-default btn-selectspacer2">Deselect All</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-infospacer" role="button"       data-toggle="collapse" href="#helpInfo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="helpInfo">More Info</a></button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Faisal, I did try that, but when changing the size of the browser window the alignment/margin were still lost. I've tried both em and percentages.

Comment: A very simple solution that works for me. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: See my comment to Andrei below. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexPho Did you tried once the one i suggested above?

Comment: Faisal, writing most of your answer in caps is not a good idea. You might want to learn [SO markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting of your answers. Also please note that TwitterBoostrap, from version 4 up uses its own **xl** size for large devices but uses a different media break-point than the repo you linked so chances are it will no longer be maintained after TB4 release and your link will probably lead to a 404 when this happens.

Comment: Another minor thing about your answer: `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"` does the exact same thing as `class="col-xs-12"` or `class="col-lg-12"`. Using them together only shows the extent of your knowledge about Twitter Bootstrap and CSS in general, but does not change the behavior of the element.